# Referencing a file inside of a Project without using its absolute path?

Tags: c#

I'm using StreamReader to dynamically replace content in an HTML template. The HTML file has been imported into my project.

Right now I'm having to referencing the HTML file a static location on my dev box because I'm not able to find the right syntax to reference it once it's been imported into my VS project.

How do I refer to the file without using an absolute path?

Current implementation for reference:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\n00b\Desktop\EmailTemplate.html");
{
     body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a path relative to the *.exe inside the solution? Can you tell us exactly where this file is? The code is strange. Why the curly braces?

Comment: Depends on how you've added it to the project. You could set it to copy to output folder on build, or you could just embed it into the exe as a resource.

Comment: I this a desktop application or web application?

Comment: This is a desktop application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found two solutions to this:

1. If you don't care if the external file is visible in the build directory/installdir of your app:

   ```
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"../../EmailTemplate.html");
           {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
   ```
2. If you want your external file to be invisible once compiled:

   ```
       var embeddedResource = "<namespace>.EmailTemplate.html";
       using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(embeddedResource))
       {
           StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
           body = sr.ReadToEnd();
       }
   ```

Note the 2nd solution requires adding your external file and changing the build action to "Embedded Resource" on the properties menu of that file within Visual Studio.

Comment: GetManifestResourceStream is like making a boat using stone tools. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

One common thing I've seen is to put the file's location in a configuration file. This lets you change the file location at will without having to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as an embedded resource and extract it this way.

```
using (Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<namespace>.Resources.EmailTemplate.html"))
```

per your comment

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<namespace>.Resources.EmailTemplate.html"))
{
    body = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does Stream have a method equivalent to ReadToEnd()? Otherwise this solution will not work without refactoring the code elsewhere.

Comment: StreamReader has a constructor that takes a stream object.

Comment: Come on, we've had resource files since forever. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio Why bother with manifest resource streams when you can access your resource via a strongly typed property?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways to do this, In a desktop application, the current directory of the .exe is set to the directory where it is launched from by default.  Unless that is changed by launching the .exe by a shortcut with special settings, or by another process using a special feature, it should be the default value.  If that is the case, you can just use a relative path.  For example, if you have a file named "data.txt" in a folder called "things" inside a folder called "stuff" in the same directory as your app, you can just us the relative path "stuff/things/data.txt" directly and Windows will work it out for you.

If you need to be absolutely sure you are targeting that file, even if the app launches with a modified current directory, you can get the .exe's path, and combine it with a relative path using `System.IO.Path.Combine`.

```
var appPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var filePath = "stuff/things/data.txt"
var fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, filePath)
```

If, for some reason, you need to up "up" from the application's directory, you can use  ".." to represent that parent folder of a directory. So "../data.txt" would look in the folder that *contains* the current directory for a file named "data.txt".

---

You could also change the app's current directory when it starts to be the directory of the .exe, and then reference everything via relative path, as in the first example.

```
var appPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(appPath);
```